# Get multiple product URL using Prestashop API

Tags: php, api, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

this is standard single product link, but i need multiple product link, how can i do.
single product link example: $productUrl = 'http:// example.com/index.php?controller=product&id_product=' . $productId;

Comment: What do you mean with multiple? Do you expect to get a page with multiple products being displayed?

Comment: example: https://example.com/index.php?controller=cart&action=show&add&id_product=22&add&id_product=23&add&id_product=24& and more products add

Comment: &add&id_product=22 &add&id_product=23 &add&id_product=24

Comment: Do you want to add multiple products to the cart?

Comment: yes, using just link.

Comment: As far as I know there is no link structure for adding multiple products at once. One solution could be adding multiple products with JavaScript, in the front-end. There al also backend options. Please provide more context of your situation.

Comment: You might want to look at the "Compare" class!.. you can pass different product ids to the page & show up to 6 different products on 1 compare page? also have the option to add to cart for each!.. ?

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
Width class cart : 

updateQty($quantity_1, $id_product_1, $id_product_attribute_1 = NULL, $id_customization = false, $operator = 'up')
updateQty($quantity_2, $id_product_2, $id_product_attribute_2 = NULL, $id_customization = false, $operator = 'up')
updateQty($quantity_3, $id_product_3, $id_product_attribute_3 = NULL, $id_customization = false, $operator = 'up')
...
```

Regards